# Difference between two FindByIdAsync in Identity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

There are two version of various methods in both `UserManager` and `UserStore` classes. So my question is:

1. Why this is?
2. When to use which and for what?

So what I have a an idea is that `UserStore` for finding user and creating user, it for user related actions. But why there are same methods in `UserManager` too.

Additional question: Do I need to use `UserStore` object created and use in `UserManager` methods (like `FindByIdAsync`) to call `UserStore` methods (like `FindByIdAsync`). But this doesn't make any sense...

Microsoft is not that nice to help developers on MSDN, so need to know from here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserStore` is a helper class that is used in `UserManager`. 
In fact all that `UserManager.FindByIdAsync` is doing is calling `UserStore.FindByIdAsync` - you can see it in [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/a24b776676f12cf7f0e13944783cf8e379b3ef70/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs#L422).

It is a very rare occasion that you need to use `UserStore` directly - I never had to use it, all my dealing with Identity was always through `UserManager` or `RoleManager`. And `IUserStore` exists so the framework can put an isolation layer for storage - if you'd like to implement your own storage, you can implement `IUserStore` and provide it for `UserManager`.

Comment: I have implemented my own `storage` so I have implemented `IUserStore` And I didnt feel the need to do anything with `FindByIdAsync` in `UserManager`. But you are saying opposite. I am still bit confused about what I can use this method in `UserManager` for?

Comment: @Alex well, it does what it says on the tin - finds you a user object if you provde an ID. Usually when working with Identity you need more than just storage - like generate user tokens for password resets or change passwords. This can't be done with `IUserStore`. And if you inject `UserManager` in your dependencies (controllers) that will provide you with all the stuff you need, without having to have 2 dependencies on UserManager and UserStorage.

Comment: Also the link you posted is Identity Framework code?